# How To Find All Methods Returning Type in Javadoc?

Tags: java, javadoc

I am using a large and unfamiliar API and would like to find all the ways of obtaining a particular class or interface. Is there a way in Javadocs to find all the methods that return such a type? If not, what are some good ways? (I'm using IntelliJ.)

Comment: How do you find all uses in Javadoc?

Comment: @fge: I'd like to make your answer the accepted one, but can't do that to a comment.

Comment: OK, answer provided!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the **standard** Javadoc layout, you cannot do that specifically.

However, you can find all usages of a particular class, provided you are on the javadoc page for that class: at the top of the page, you have a set of links; one of them is called `Use` (it's right next to `Class`). It will indeed list all the uses of that class, whether it be as a return value *or* as an argument.

In IDEA itself, if you have the cursor on the class you want, you can press Alt+F7, you'll have the option to search for the uses of a particular class in your project, or your project PLUS the libraries you depend upon.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `IntelliJ`, for finding a particular Class, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to find any class you have in your project. To find all methods that return a type, I would go with Find Usages option, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. You can refine your results afterward.

Additionally, if you have a lengthy class open in your editor, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> to open the File Structure view. Start typing the returning type you are looking for, you will get a shorter list of potential methods you want.

Answer (score -2):

Other than javadoc, you can get the return type of all methods of a specific class by Reflection.

Comment: (I am not a downvoter) This is not what the OP asked; the OP specifically asked how to view usages of a given method of a given class. If you were to do this using programmation only, even reflection wouldn't be enough, you'd have to walk the bytecode of each method, or parse the source...